# How to await the socket id on flutter client

Tags: flutter, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I successfully implemented socketio on my clientside in flutter. For the backend im using a really basic node.js server. In my root `main.dart` im calling `socket.connect()` initially, then im logging in a mockuser to my app with the given `socket.id`. Everything just works fine. Now when I call my `signout()` function, the mock user is logging out and the function calls `socket.disconnect()`, this also works fine. Now when I want so `signin()` calling my signin function, im also calling `socket.connect()` this time, because its not initially connecting anymore from my `main.dart`, but im not able to pass the `socket.id` to my mockuser, since there is no way for me atm how I can await the connection to the socket server and WAIT for the `socketid`.

my socket

```
class SocketRepository {
  late Socket socket;
  Auth auth = Auth.instance;

  static final SocketRepository _socketRepo = SocketRepository._internal();

  factory SocketRepository() {
    return _socketRepo;
  }
  SocketRepository._internal() {
    try {
      socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3000', <String, dynamic>{
        'transports': ['websocket'],
        'autoConnect': false,
      });
      socket.on('connect', (_) {
        print(socket.id);
      });

      //! Error
      socket.on("error", (data) {
        /// You could call the onError from the chat bloc here (if any)
      });

      //? Disconnected
      socket.on('disconnect', (_) {
        // Do some cleanup if needed
      });
    } catch (e) {
      /// You could call the onError from the chat bloc here (if any)
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  void connect() {
    socket.connect();
  }

  void disconnect() {
    socket.disconnect();
  }

  
}
```

user repository calling signin, signout (Here i cant await the socket id in my signin)

```
class UserRepository {
  Auth auth = Auth.instance;

  //UserRepository({required this.auth});

  // sign in with username
  //TODO: change hardcoded username to email and passwort later on
  Future<User> signIn() async {
try{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  if(SocketRepository().socket.id == null){
    print('connecting to socket again');
    SocketRepository().connect();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  }
  //print('connectedId : ${connectedId!}');
  final socketId = auth.currentUser.socketId;
  var finalUser = User(id: 1, socketId: SocketRepository().socket.id, userName: 'Logged in User');
  auth.currentUser = finalUser;
  print('signed id with credentials: ${finalUser}');
  return auth.currentUser;
}catch(e){
  print(e.toString());
  throw e;
}
```

}

```
  //TODO: change hardcoded username to email and passwort later 
  Future<User> signOut() async {
    try{
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      var credentials = User.empty;
      auth.currentUser = credentials;
      SocketRepository().disconnect();
      print('signed out with credentials: ${auth.currentUser}');
      return auth.currentUser;
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      throw e;
    }
  }

}
```

calling `socket.connect()` in my `main.dart` initially which works fine

```
void main() {
  SocketRepository().connect();
  BlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    },
    blocObserver: SimpleBlocObserver(),
  );
}
```

EDIT: By adding a hardcoded delay to my `signin()` function I can make it work actually. But i'm searching for a better approach..

```
  Future<Null> delay(int milliseconds) {
  return new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds));
}

  // sign in with username
  //TODO: change hardcoded username to email and passwort later on
  Future<User> signIn() async {
    try{
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      if(SocketRepository().socket.id == null){
        print('connecting to socket again');
       
        SocketRepository().connect();
        await delay(1000);
        if(auth.socketId == null){
          await delay(4000);
        }
      }
      //print('connectedId : ${connectedId!}');
      final socketId = auth.socketId;
      var finalUser = User(id: 1, socketId: socketId, userName: 'Logged in User');
      auth.currentUser = finalUser;
      print('signed id with credentials: ${finalUser}');
      return auth.currentUser;
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

---

**EDIT with the help of Pierre Monier**

**`Signin()` function awaiting the getter `socketid`**

```
  Future<User> signIn() async {
    try {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      if (socketRepo.socket.id == null) {
        socketRepo.connect();
        final connectionId = await socketRepo.socketId;
      }
      auth.currentUser = User(id: 1, socketId: auth.socketId, userName: 'Logged in User');     print('signed id with credentials: ${auth.currentUser}');
      return auth.currentUser;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

**Socketrepository**

```
class SocketRepository {
  late Socket socket;
  Auth auth = Auth.instance;

  Completer<String?> _socketIdCompleter = Completer();
  Future<String?> get socketId => _socketIdCompleter.future;


  static final SocketRepository _socketRepo = SocketRepository._internal();

  factory SocketRepository() {
    return _socketRepo;
  }

  SocketRepository._internal() {
    try {
      socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3000', <String, dynamic>{
        'transports': ['websocket'],
        'autoConnect': false,
      });
    
      socket.on('connect', (_) {
        print(socket.id);
      });

      //? Reconnected
      /// Just in case user gets disconnected from server we reconnect ans send
      /// the same payload
      socket.on('reconnect', (_) {
        auth.socketId = socket.id;
      });

      //! Error
      /// You could call the onError from the chat bloc here (if any)
      socket.on("error", (data) => _socketIdCompleter.completeError(data));

      //? Disconnected
      socket.on('disconnect', (_) => '');

      //? on connected
      socket.onConnect((_) {
        auth.socketId = socket.id;
        _socketIdCompleter.complete(socket.id);
      });

    } catch (e) {
      /// You could call the onError from the chat bloc here (if any)
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  void connect() {
    //streamSocket = StreamSocket();
    if(_socketIdCompleter.isCompleted == true) _socketIdCompleter = Completer();
    socket.connect();
  }

  void disconnect() {
    //streamSocket.dispose();
    socket.disconnect();
    if(_socketIdCompleter.isCompleted == false) _socketIdCompleter.complete(); 
  }
```

Comment: Does anybody know how to await the socket connection and receive the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good use case for a [Completer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html).

Basically it's a object that can produce `Future`. In your `SocketRepository` you can add a property named `_socketIdCompleter` of type `Completer<Type of socket.id>`.

Then you can add a getter method like this

```
Future<Type of socket.id> get socketId => _socketIdCompleter.future
```

Finally you just have to change your callback method for something like this

```
      socket.on('connect', (_) {
        _socketIdCompleter.complete(socket.id);
      });

      //! Error
      socket.on("error", (data) {
        _socketIdCompleter.completeError(data);
      });
```

This should do the job, you can just await for the getter `socketId` to complete, after calling `SocketRepository().connect()`

Comment: hey there, thank you for your approach, its really clean! When im singing out and signing back in it throws an error which says  Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed
how can I rerun or recreate the future?

Comment: In my Socketrepository I wrote this: Completer<String?> _socketIdCompleter = Completer();
  Future<String?> get socketId => _socketIdCompleter.future; now can I just add _socketIdCompleter = Completer(); in my connect function?

Comment: Hum I see. One way of doing this can be to have a non final _socketIdCompleter, and reassign on disconnect. This way your completer can complete again (because it's a new one)

```dart
      socket.on('disconnect', (_) {
        _socketIdCompleter = Completer()
      });
```

Comment: do you mean like this? Check my edit please

Comment: it works fine actually and it looks like with the check im making sure im creating and closing the future only if its needed or closing if its still there but not needed anymore

Comment: looks good to me :)